# Create new Rails project with no internet connection (in Windows cmd) cause bundle error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My computer is behind a proxy, so I have no internet connection on my cmd, I've get RailsInstaller and installed it on my computer running Windows 7.
When I try to create a new Rails project by

```
rails new simple_cms
```

it works until command shows

```
run  bundle install
```

it waits for a long time then I get this error

```
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/
```

What else should I install, so I can create and work on Rails project without an internet connection?

My Ruby version is 1.9.3 and Rails version is 3.2.13

Comment: If you manage to have a connection during the creation (to let bundler do its magic), you can then work offline. But don't you need to, say, google for stuff? So internet is a must have, I'm afraid.

Comment: Waaaaait, how did you ask this question here?

Comment: @Date Newton: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What bundle install command do is its install gems from https://rubygems.org/ to your system.

You could not run bundle install without internet connection.

You should have all the gems in you system which you used in your application.

If you have your gems installed, you can use **bundle install --local**. It is not require internet connection

Comment: Is there any package that I can install all at once?

Comment: if you not have packages in your system then you need to do bundle install once then you can continue developing without any internet connection.if you install new gem then again you need to install bundle from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

First go to the app folder than run bundle install.
You can't run bundle install without internet connection, if your gems is not installed.